# Tests failing in bitbucket's pipeline

Tags: node.js, date, jestjs, bitbucket, pipeline

I am working with tests involving date for the first time, and needed to test if a function converted a string to the date format with the expected timezone (`America/Sao Paulo`) for me to persist in my database, however these tests are successfully completed locally and are failing when run in the bitbucket pipeline, has anyone experienced something similar or have any suggestions on how to solve it?

Here is the code for the function and the test:

```
import { DateTime } from 'luxon';

export const date = {
  now: (timezone = 'America/Sao_Paulo'): DateTime => DateTime.now().setZone(timezone),
  convertISODateToJSDateWithTimezone: (date: string, timezone = 'America/Sao_Paulo') =>
    DateTime.fromISO(date).setZone(timezone).toJSDate(),
};
```

Test:

```
import { date } from '../date';

describe('Date Helper', () => {
  it.each([
    ['2000-01-01T00:00:00', '2000-01-01T02:00:00.000Z'],
    ['2010-12-31T00:00:00', '2010-12-31T02:00:00.000Z'],
  ])('Should be able to convert ISO date to JS date with timezone (%s -> %s)', (isoDate, expected) => {
    const jsDateWithTimezone = date.convertISODateToJSDateWithTimezone(isoDate);

    expect(jsDateWithTimezone).toEqual(new Date(expected));
  });
});
```

Pipeline error:

```
FAIL libs/shared/src/helpers/_tests_/date.spec.ts
  ● Date Helper › Should be able to convert ISO date to JS date with timezone (2000-01-01T00:00:00 -> 2000-01-01T02:00:00.000Z)
    expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality
    Expected: 2000-01-01T02:00:00.000Z
    Received: 2000-01-01T00:00:00.000Z
       8 |     const jsDateWithTimezone = date.convertISODateToJSDateWithTimezone(isoDate);
       9 |
    > 10 |     expect(jsDateWithTimezone).toEqual(new Date(expected));
         |                                ^
      11 |   });
      12 | });
      13 |
      at libs/shared/src/helpers/_tests_/date.spec.ts:10:32
  ● Date Helper › Should be able to convert ISO date to JS date with timezone (2010-12-31T00:00:00 -> 2010-12-31T02:00:00.000Z)
    expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality
    Expected: 2010-12-31T02:00:00.000Z
    Received: 2010-12-31T00:00:00.000Z
       8 |     const jsDateWithTimezone = date.convertISODateToJSDateWithTimezone(isoDate);
       9 |
    > 10 |     expect(jsDateWithTimezone).toEqual(new Date(expected));
         |                                ^
      11 |   });
      12 | });
      13 |
      at libs/shared/src/helpers/_tests_/date.spec.ts:10:32
```

I tried to solve this problem by setting the process.env.TZ to the desired timezone in the test environment, but was still unsuccessful.

Can anyone with experience with tests involving dates or who has experienced a similar situation help me?

Comment: Hello, could you please include test's failing reason, from BB pipeline logs?

Comment: Sure, I just edited the question content